# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: and executeUpdate won't work

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Good day guys! I have this program that checks whether the current password matches a password in the database. Then the new password should update the current password that is in the database. The passwords are converted into md5 structure. Now, all perfectly works except that the database won't update. A MySQLSyntaxErrorException occurs and also the executeUpdate method won't work. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
if(!rs.next()){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Retype your password.");
                    response.sendRedirect("/Project1/ChangePassword.jsp");
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "RESULTSET");
                    pswrd = rs.getString(1);

                    if(md5CurrentPasswrd.equals(pswrd)){
                        if(newPassword.equals(confirmPassword)){
                            digest.update(newPassword.getBytes(), 0, newPassword.length());
                            md5NewPasswrd = new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16);

                            Connection conn2 = null;
                            String conStr = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chkdb?user=root&password=";
                            conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(conStr);

                            PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn2.prepareStatement("UPDATE accounts SET password=? /n"
                                    + " WHERE password=?");
                            prepStmt.setString(1,md5NewPasswrd);
                            prepStmt.setString(2,md5CurrentPasswrd);

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated1!"); //The program passes this.

                            prepStmt.executeUpdate();
                            prepStmt.close();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated2!"); //The program does not reach this.
                            response.sendRedirect("/Project1/summary.jsp");
                        }else{
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Passwords did not match!");
                            response.sendRedirect("/Project1/summary.jsp");
                        }
                    }  
                }
```

Comment: please show your exception

Comment: BTW what is the /n for ?

Comment: What is /n (UPDATE accounts SET password=? /n) doing in your query??

Comment: @ScaryWombat it was for nextline. I deleted it and just made it a one liner. Then it worked! Thanks! Sorry, I'm just a newbie.

Comment: Are you changing the password for all users having my old password?

Comment: 1.) What's the error message? 2.) Storing MD5-hashed, unsalted paswords are faaar from secure. 3.) Updating based on `WHERE password=?` seems risky - what if there are two identical passwords (or password-hashes when salted)?

Comment: @JoopEggen no, I'm only changing the password entered at the current password field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/n` should be `\n` or simply space.

Answer (score 2):

Change your query from

```
UPDATE accounts SET password=? /n"
             + " WHERE password=?
```

To

```
UPDATE accounts SET password=? WHERE password=?
```